# Passenger misses development gem in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, bundler, environment

I've got a strange behaviour on my production server: I deploy my Rails 3 application via Capistrano to the production server. The Capistrano script restarts passenger at the end of deployment. When I open the application I see a passenger error message:

```
Could not find autotest-fsevent-0.2.4 in any of the sources
(Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Of course autotest-fsevent is not installed in my production environment (and even can't be installed on Ubuntu...)

The environment is set in apache's virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  PassengerMinInstances 1

  ServerName test.myapp.de
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public

  RailsEnv production
  RackEnv production

  <Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public/>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all
    AddOutputFilterbyType DEFLATE text/html
    FileEtag none
  </Directory>

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/www/myapp/shared/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/myapp/shared/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'simple-navigation'
gem 'geokit'
gem 'geokit-rails3', :git => "git://github.com/loosecubes/geokit-rails3.git"
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'delocalize'
gem 'prawn'

group :development do
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
#gem 'ruby-debug19'
gem 'ruby-debug'
gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.2'
gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'rcov'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Why does passenger (or bundler) think it needs ALL gems instead only the gems for production environment?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the bundler capistrano recipes?

Make sure this is in your `config/deploy.rb`

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Basically it will invoke bundle with the `--without development test` option, which should only install the production gems. If you are just doing a regular `bundle`, it will install try to install the gems for all environments.

Comment: OK, I added that to my deploy.rb. The deployment process now didn't work at all, I think because of a git-referenced gem in my Gemfile (geokit-rails3). Since this gem is now also availible on rubygems, I removed the github-reference and TADA: my Deployment process is working again. Thanks for all your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have your `RAILS_ENV` environment variable either undefined, or set inadvertently to `development` which could cause the wrong set of gems to be loaded. You might want to dig in to your `deploy.rb` script to ensure that the correct environment is set.

You should have something like this in `deploy.rb`:

```
task :production do
  # ...

  set :rails_env, 'production'

  # ...
end
```

You should be able to verify that this is set correctly by doing this:

```
cap production shell
cap> echo $RAILS_ENV
** [out :: myserver] production
```